# problem with random number generation

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

```
ArrayList <String> fil = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList <String> lif = new ArrayList<String>();

int x=0;
long tim = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
Random random = new Random(tim); 
for(int i=0;i<fil.size();i++)
{
 x =random.nextInt(fil.size());
         for(int y=0;y<lif.size();y++)
         {
             if(fil.get(x).equals(lif.get(y)))
             {
                 i--;
                 continue;
             }
         }
         System.out.println("Set the value of x"+x);
          lif.add(i, fil.get(x));//array index out of bound exception


     }
```

I'm trying to copy the contents of ArrayList `fil` to `lif` in a different order, but I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` in the commented line. I'm using a nested for-loop to check if the elements of new ArrayList are unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone :) I used Collections.shuffle method and its great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try [Collections.copy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) and [Collections.shuffle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) methods.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't [Collections.shuffle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The "lif"-ArrayList must be preallocated to hold "fil.size()" elements before reshuffeling the contents. Try adding "fil.size()" null elements before entering you're for loop.

Note! This is a very uneffective approach to do reshuffeling, see [Collections.reshuffle()](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_Shuffle.html) for a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(fil.get(x).equals(lif.get(y)))
{
    i--;
    continue;
}
```

One possible problem is if 'i' is 0 (zero). The decrement `i--` will set 'i' to -1 which will cause an exception with...`lif.add(i, fil.get(x));`

That may not be the answer but you should be checking that i, x and y are all within the bounds of the ArrayList objects.

Answer (score 0):

Modify commented line to:

```
lif.add(fil.get(x));
```

This should fix exception. However, your algorithm doesn't look very good.

Answer (score -2):

Change the code to this and check if that works

```
x =random.nextInt(fil.size() - 1);
```

Comment: From nextInt(int n) documentation:
Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.